# mkdir from grep and pipe

Tags: grep, pipe, mkdir

I have this little script that puts out some dir paths. 
I want to mkdir all those paths.

```
for filename in $(git ls-files | grep .java | grep -v 'com/foo' | sed -e 's/\(.java[^/]*\).java/\1/' | uniq)
do
echo "$filename" | sed -e 's/com\/old\/old/com\/new/' | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/'
done
```

So new dir are created... com/old/old = com/new

But I cannot get that mkdir to work... I tried..

```
path=$("$filename" | sed -e 's/com\/old\/old/com\/new/' | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/')
mkdir -p "$path"
```

That is just messing with the file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do all the substitutions in one `sed` command, and it can also filter out `com/foo`.  Then pipe the output to a `while read` loop.

```
git ls-files | grep .java |
        sed -e '/com\/foo/d' -e 's/\(.java[^/]*\).java/\1/' -e 's/com\/old\/old/com\/new/' -e 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/' |
        uniq | while read path; do
    mkdir -p "$path"
done
```

Here's how to do your `git mv`:

```
git ls-files | grep .java |
        sed -e '/com\/intuit/d' -e 's/\(.java[^/]*\).java/\1/' | uniq | 
    while read path; do
        dir=$(echo "$path" | sed -e 's/com\/old\/old/com\/new/' -e 's/\(.*\)\/.*/\1/')
        mkdir -p "$dir"
        git mv "$path" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: A little update.. so the mkdir is working, but I actually also need to git mv the files after the dir is created. So I need the original file path. This just echo the original path and then the new path.


for file in $(git ls-files | grep .java | grep -v 'com/intuit' | sed -e 's/\(.java[^/]*\).java/\1/' | uniq); 
do
echo $file
echo $file | sed -e 's/com\/old\/old/com\/new/'
done

Comment: Just remove the `sed` expression that removes the filename. In the body of the loop, use `dirname $path` to get the directory portion for `mkdir`, and then move the file into it.

Comment: I was doing this..
git ls-files | grep .java | sed -e '/com\/intuit/d' -e 's/\(.java[^/]*\).java/\1/' | uniq | while read path; do
    git mv $path `$path | sed -e 's/com\/old\/old/com\/new/'`
done

But that is just messing with the contents of the file.. ( that actually also need to do in the next step )

Comment: It's hard to read that unformatted mess, especially since SO uses backticks for markup. Don't try to put code in comments, add to your question or start a new one. Anyway, I've updated my answer, does that help?

Comment: Oh ya I see, you echo the $path into the sed. And create a variable dir that can then be used as input to the git mv